# Jace, Telepath Unbound and Casting a Spell from the Graveyard

Tags: magic-the-gathering, magic-duels

I was playing MTG Duels.

I had [Jace, Telepath Unbound](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=398435) on the battlefield and activated its second ability:

> You may cast target instant or sorcery card from your graveyard this
>   turn. If that card would be put into your graveyard this turn, exile
>   it instead.

The target was [Adverse Conditions](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=401803) in the graveyard. However, there was no effect and it wasn't exiled either.

Why was there no effect?

Comment: Why did you include "Hidden zone" in your question title?

Comment: That was my guess from reading the rullings :  If, at any time, the card goes to a hidden zone (such as your hand or your library), the effect loses track of the card. It won’t be exiled, even if that card is put into your graveyard later that turn.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know how MTG Duels exactly works but my guess is this, the card says

> You **may** cast target instant or sorcery card from your graveyard this turn

Which means that you are able to target a card in your graveyard but decide to not cast it. After this ability resolves you still have to manually cast it from your graveyard. You have the entire turn for that. It doesn't automatically get cast when the ability resolves.

Comment: I can confirm this is how Jace works. Once his loyalty ability has resolved, you have to zoom into your graveyard, then zoom into the selected card (will be highlighted red). You will see an ability at the bottom of the card saying "Cast this card" (May have to scroll the card text if there is a lot of text on the card). Once you click this ability, it will begin casting the card.