# Spells are not exiled by Jace, Telepath Unbound's second ability in MTG Duels

Tags: magic-the-gathering, magic-duels

I used [Jace, Telepath Unbound](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Jace%2C%20Telepath%20Unbound)'s second ability, which is casting a spell from the graveyard. It says the spell will be exiled.

However, it didn't. For example, [Adverse Conditions](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Adverse%20Conditions) was in the graveyard when I activated the Jace's second ability. And Adverse Conditions was cast, but didn't get exiled and instead went into the graveyard again.

Why so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jace, Telepath Unbound and Casting a Spell from the Graveyard](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/29687/jace-telepath-unbound-and-casting-a-spell-from-the-graveyard)

Comment: @MarcDingena Not a duplicate, involves the same cards but is asking different things.

Comment: @Hackworth I stand corrected. The difference in both question is so tiny I actually missed that. How can I retract my flag?

Comment: @MarcDingena Don't worry about it, it will expire after a few days.

Comment: @MarcDingena If you click on the "close" again, there will be an option to retract your vote.

Comment: @tsuma534 that's nice, but I don't actually have the rep to close. I used a flag "Duplicate". I can't retract the flag.

Comment: There's no flag-retraction to do. The flag put this question into the Close review queue. It'll go through there and either be closed or voted upon to be left open.

Answer (score 6):

Should it have been exiled? Yup.  You cast it from your graveyard, it went on the stack, resolved then returned to your graveyard.  Going to your graveyard should have been replaced with exiling the card.

Why didn't it?  No idea.  It's probably a bug.  With a game and rules as complex as Magic's, it wouldn't surprise me that something doesn't work like it is supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

[Jace, Telepath Unbound](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Jace%2C%20Telepath%20Unbound)'s second ability states that "If the card (the spell cast from the graveyard) would be put into the graveyard this turn, exile it instead." This means whatever spell you pull from the graveyard, if it were to return to the graveyard by **any** means (casting, countered, etc,.) then the card gets exiled instead of going to the graveyard. In short, when you use Jace's second ability, any card you cast from the graveyard will most likely be exiled.

There are ways to prevent this with other spells or abilities. For example, if you cast a spell with Buyback (e.g., [Walk the Aeons](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Walk%20the%20Aeons)), it never goes to the graveyard, and Jace's ability will not exile it. Likewise, if you cast a spell from your graveyard and then [Remand](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Remand) your own spell, it returns to your hand.

Comment: The nature of the question is that yes, it *ought* to get exiled, but it wasn't.

Comment: @doppelgreener This answers the first half of the question, "Should the card be exiled?". The second half of the question, "Why was it not exiled?", is speculation because we don't know the entire board state (and I don't trust the OP to recall it perfectly anyway, because he doesn't necessarily know what to look for). Ultimately the OP is either leaving out some important details, or there is a bug in the game.

Comment: The spells mentioned in the second half of this answer aren't in the Magic Duels game. As far as I know, there are no spells or abilities in the game that will take a spell from the stack to anywhere other either the graveyard or exile. I may be mistaken as I've not seen all the new cards added but the cards are mainly from Origins onward (Not every card gets into the game either).

Comment: @ProgenitorMimic Should I roll back my edit then? I was trying to provide examples of cards that would make it work that way - not necessarily examples from the game itself - so that the OP knows what kinds of abilities to look for. I definitely don't want to add irrelevant fluff to an answer that I didn't write.

Comment: I don't know. Looks like we have never had questions about the duels games before today. I don't know if these sort of questions should be directed to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/ as they have a tag for the game and more people might have played it over there.

Answer (score 0):

There was an update to Magic Duels just under a week ago. There seems to have a lot of bugs that got introduced. This may be the case but I can't access the bug list at the moment because I'm at work (Although it may be unreported, may just be a bug with just this card combination). There is no date set where a patch is to be released at the time of writing.